# What system component is responsible for creating my USB device?

Tags: linux, usb, yocto

I'm commissioning an embedded system (AM335x, Yocto with kernel 3.19). When I plug in a USB VCOM adapter, I get the encouraging message:

usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using musb-hdrc

but I never receive the longed-for follow-up which should look something like:

usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=????, idProduct=????

So, the question is, what system component is generating the first message, and failing to generate the second?

The obvious answer seems to be musb_hdrc, which I believe is a kernel module. I do not know through what mechanism a kernel module is configured - is that through the .config file, as for the kernel? And I have no idea what setting this module might have (if it is involved at all) that would cause it do nothing upon noticing my USB device.

Can anyone shed any light on what might be going on, here? It's, in most respects, an off-the-shelf Yocto build.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/writing_musb_glue_layer/linux-musb-basics.html) is a very good kernel documentation on musb. May be you can go through the source files.